# How do you create an interface with a public IP address with Google compute node.js api?

Tags: node.js, api, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I use the Google official api :https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/compute

There are examples but none showing how to create an interface with a public IP.

I can't use `http:true` as I need to have a specific TCP port to be opened.

Answer (score 1):

Create a firewall rule to allow connections to the port on the VM's public IP.

Reference from: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/compute/latest/Network.html#createFirewall

```
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const compute = new Compute();
const network = compute.network('network-name');

const config = {
  protocols: {
    tcp: [3000],
    udp: [] // An empty array means all ports are allowed.
  },

  ranges: ['0.0.0.0/0']
};

function callback(err, firewall, operation, apiResponse) {
  // `firewall` is a Firewall object.

  // `operation` is an Operation object that can be used to check the status
  // of the request.
}

network.createFirewall('new-firewall-name', config, callback);

//-
// If the callback is omitted, we'll return a Promise.
//-
network.createFirewall('new-firewall-name', config).then(function(data) {
  const firewall = data[0];
  const operation = data[1];
  const apiResponse = data[2];
});
```